# System.NotSupportedException Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, exception, icollection

I have an app that has a 3 step signup process,

1. Name, email, password (inside signup_vm);
2. User details (inside User_ProfileINC_vm);
3. Medication intake (inside UserMedicineINC_vm).

I am able to get through 1) and 2), as soon as i am navigated to 3) - i see the UI of the page but suddenly am followed by the "unhandled exception" pop-up box.

The error i am getting in the debug output:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[LoginSystem.Models.Medicine]
```

I think it is because i have this line of code inside my Medicine class (inside the models folder):

```
public virtual ICollection<Medicine_Incident> Medicine_Incident { get; set; }
```

And this Medicine_Incident is just another class that is inheriting Medicine like so:

```
public class Medicine_Incident : Medicine
```

*Medicine and Medicine_Incident defines some fields like:

```
public string Medicine_Name { get; set; }
public string Medicine_Desc { get; set; }
```

Is the use of Icollections prohibited in Xamarin?

Please let me know if you have any idea as to what's going on.
Thanks!

*App output:

```
06-19 10:26:50.382 E/EGL_emulation( 5282): tid 5308: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
06-19 10:26:50.382 W/OpenGLRenderer( 5282): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9a966180, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
06-19 10:26:50.433 E/EGL_emulation( 5282): tid 5308: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
06-19 10:26:50.433 W/OpenGLRenderer( 5282): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9a966060, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
06-19 10:26:50.663 E/EGL_emulation( 5282): tid 5308: eglSurfaceAttrib(1165): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
06-19 10:26:50.663 W/OpenGLRenderer( 5282): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9a7a0aa0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
06-19 10:26:51.898 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref LoginSystem[0x9dfec2a0] -> SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0]: 2
06-19 10:26:51.916 D/Mono    ( 5282): Unloading image System.Threading.Tasks.dll [0x9a853f00].
06-19 10:26:51.916 D/Mono    ( 5282): Image addref System.Threading.Tasks[0x9a864300] -> System.Threading.Tasks.dll[0x9cc96000]: 6
06-19 10:26:51.916 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Threading.Tasks.dll.config'.
06-19 10:26:51.916 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Threading.Tasks/System.Threading.Tasks.config'.
06-19 10:26:51.916 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0] -> System.Threading.Tasks[0x9dfed020]: 4
06-19 10:26:51.962 D/Mono    ( 5282): Unloading image System.Collections.dll [0xab2f7400].
06-19 10:26:51.962 D/Mono    ( 5282): Image addref System.Collections[0xaec94f60] -> System.Collections.dll[0x9d004f00]: 7
06-19 10:26:51.962 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Collections.dll.config'.
06-19 10:26:51.962 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Collections/System.Collections.config'.
06-19 10:26:51.962 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0] -> System.Collections[0x9dfec4e0]: 5
06-19 10:26:51.965 D/Mono    ( 5282): Unloading image System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [0xab2f7400].
06-19 10:26:51.965 D/Mono    ( 5282): Image addref System.Runtime.Extensions[0xaec94f60] -> System.Runtime.Extensions.dll[0x9d007c00]: 6
06-19 10:26:51.965 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.config'.
06-19 10:26:51.965 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Extensions/System.Runtime.Extensions.config'.
06-19 10:26:51.965 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0] -> System.Runtime.Extensions[0x9dfecb40]: 4
06-19 10:26:51.965 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0] -> SQLitePCLRaw.core[0xad9e9f40]: 2
06-19 10:26:51.975 D/Mono    ( 5282): Unloading image System.Threading.dll [0xab2f7400].
06-19 10:26:51.975 D/Mono    ( 5282): Image addref System.Threading[0xaec949c0] -> System.Threading.dll[0xb2facb00]: 7
06-19 10:26:51.975 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Threading.dll.config'.
06-19 10:26:51.975 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Threading/System.Threading.config'.
06-19 10:26:51.975 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0] -> System.Threading[0x9dfec5a0]: 5
06-19 10:26:51.983 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0] -> SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2[0xad9e9d00]: 2
06-19 10:26:51.984 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2[0xad9e9d00] -> SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3[0xad9e9e20]: 2
06-19 10:26:51.984 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3[0xad9e9e20] -> SQLitePCLRaw.core[0xad9e9f40]: 3
06-19 10:26:51.985 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2[0xad9e9d00] -> SQLitePCLRaw.core[0xad9e9f40]: 4
06-19 10:26:51.992 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport attempting to load: 'e_sqlite3'.
06-19 10:26:51.994 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/LoginSystem.Android/files/.__override__/libe_sqlite3': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LoginSystem.Android-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/LoginSystem.Android/files/.__override__/libe_sqlite3" not found'.
06-19 10:26:51.995 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/LoginSystem.Android/files/.__override__/libe_sqlite3.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LoginSystem.Android-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/LoginSystem.Android/files/.__override__/libe_sqlite3.so" not found'.
06-19 10:26:51.995 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libe_sqlite3': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LoginSystem.Android-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libe_sqlite3" not found'.
06-19 10:26:51.996 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libe_sqlite3.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LoginSystem.Android-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libe_sqlite3.so" not found'.
06-19 10:26:51.996 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport error loading library 'libe_sqlite3': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/LoginSystem.Android-1/lib/x86/libe_sqlite3" not found'.
06-19 10:26:51.999 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport loaded library 'libe_sqlite3.so'.
06-19 10:26:52.000 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('libe_sqlite3.so').
06-19 10:26:52.000 D/Mono    ( 5282): Searching for 'sqlite3_libversion_number'.
06-19 10:26:52.007 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('libe_sqlite3.so').
06-19 10:26:52.007 D/Mono    ( 5282): Searching for 'sqlite3_open_v2'.
06-19 10:26:52.028 D/Mono    ( 5282): DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('libe_sqlite3.so').
06-19 10:26:52.028 D/Mono    ( 5282): Searching for 'sqlite3_busy_timeout'.
06-19 10:26:52.036 D/Mono    ( 5282): Unloading image System.Reflection.dll [0xab2fab00].
06-19 10:26:52.036 D/Mono    ( 5282): Image addref System.Reflection[0xaec950e0] -> System.Reflection.dll[0x9d005400]: 8
06-19 10:26:52.036 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Reflection.dll.config'.
06-19 10:26:52.036 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection/System.Reflection.config'.
06-19 10:26:52.036 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0] -> System.Reflection[0x9dfec600]: 6
06-19 10:26:52.037 D/Mono    ( 5282): Unloading image System.Linq.dll [0xab2fab00].
06-19 10:26:52.038 D/Mono    ( 5282): Image addref System.Linq[0xaec950e0] -> System.Linq.dll[0x9d007200]: 7
06-19 10:26:52.038 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Linq.dll.config'.
06-19 10:26:52.038 D/Mono    ( 5282): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Linq/System.Linq.config'.
06-19 10:26:52.038 D/Mono    ( 5282): Assembly Ref addref SQLite-net[0xad9e9dc0] -> System.Linq[0x9dfec900]: 5
06-19 10:26:52.169 E/Surface ( 5282): getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9bd87280
InspectorDebugSession(9): HandleTargetEvent: UnhandledException
06-19 10:27:04.139 I/art     ( 5282): Thread[2,tid=5287,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xab32c500,peer=0x12c770a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
06-19 10:27:04.224 I/art     ( 5282): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: please include the exception stack trace

Comment: Alright just did, thanks!

Comment: that's the App output, not the stack trace

Comment: Every time someone uses underscore for c# instead of camel casing a kitten dies painfully

Comment: uhhhh, i am a noob, if you couldn't already tell. Where can i find the stack trace?

Comment: Looking at this link the problem has to do with sqlite: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18548/dont-know-about-system-collections-generic-icollection-1

Comment: That is correct! I guess i need to find an alternative to ICollections for SQLite. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a ForeignKey to your Medicine_Incident class declaration that references the Medicine it is associated to.

```
public class Medicine_Incident : Medicine
{
    // Whatever properties you have already defined

    ...

    // This is your link to your medicine PrimaryKey
    public int MedicineId { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to leave the ICollection in your Medicine class declaration for convenience purposes, throw an IgnoreAttribute over it like so:

```
public class Medicine 
{
    // Whatever other stuff you have declared

    ...

    [Ignore]
    public virtual ICollection<Medicine_Incident> Medicine_Incident { get; set; }
}
```

This ensures that SQLite does not try to create a column for the ICollection type since it doesn't know how.

Comment: Okay, makes sense, but how would i be able to replace this line?  medicine.Medicine_Incident.Add(med_inc);

Comment: var med_inc = (Medicine_Incident)BindingContext;

Comment: var medicine =  (Medicine)BindingContext;

Comment: I'd be happy to answer more questions but doing so in the comments is frowned upon in StackOverflow. If you have a complete new question to ask, feel free to start a new question with full context of the issue you are facing.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot tho! :)